# JDBC: Do I Need to Reset fetchSize on a Statement That is Guaranteed to be Closed?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Following an example in a book I am querying a table by using `setFetchSize()`. The book mentions to reset `setAutoCommit()` and `setFetchSize()` (the book doesn't close `statement` and `connection` in its example, so my snippet differs).

```scala
val connection = db.getConnection()
val statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)
connection.setAutoCommit(false)
statement.setFetchSize(25)
try {
  ...
} finally {
  statement.setFetchSize(0)  // Do I need to call it if I close the stmt?
  connection.setAutoCommit(true)
  statement.close()
  connection.close()
}
```

Resetting auto commit makes sense to me, because I guess after `close()` the connection object might be reused in a connection-pool at a later point.

However, I am curious if I need to reset the fetch size in that case. The Javadoc for `connection.prepareStatement()` in `java.sql.Connection` states:

> @return a new default `PreparedStatement` object containing the pre-compiled SQL statement

Am I right that when closing `statement` I wouldn't need to reset the fetch size by calling `setFetchSize(0)` in the finally block?

Comment: No, you don't need that. Just close the statement

Comment: It depends on your pool. Some pools will cache prepared statements. So if you say you need to reset the auto-commit flag because of pooling, then the same might apply to attributes you set on the statement. However, it appears you always set the attributes before you use the connection/statement. So pooled or no, as long as you consistently do that there is no need to reset anything. Also, some pools can be configured to reset resources returned to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a `Statement` is closed, it cannot be reused. There's no harm per se in  resetting the fetchSize, but it doesn't serve any useful purpose.

Comment: What about connection pools that cache prepared statements? Like the Tomcat JDBC pool?

Comment: @Ralf thanks for pointing out the Tomcat JDBC pool (it's what I am using). I tried various of the documented settings/interceptors and yet never experienced  that a modified fetch size survived a `connection.close()` (auto commit however does, so it is important to reset that explicitly). That said, there are quite a few settings and even after debugging/doc-reading I am not 100% sure that there might not be a combination of settings where this might be different. I will keep resetting it (better safe than sorry), but otherwise I think that Mureinik is right.

Answer (score 1):

If you close the statement you can't reuse it so anything you do on it right before or after closing would'nt change a thing.Same for the connection once you closed it you can't reuse it.(to the best of my knowledge)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems to be that way with statements (see my comment to Ralf above). It is true that once you close a connection it cannot be reused. However, if you use a pool `close()` is altered in a way, that instead of shutting down the connection the object is returned to its pool (so you get a pool of ready conns and avoid the overhead of re-connecting). In that case changes made to the connection (e.g. auto commit) might be cached (e.g. with the [Tomcat JDBC pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState))